# How to call model in Controller request $request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a query in my model, which I want to call in my controller (request $request). It's working fine when the controller parameter is controller($id). But how to pass it in $request controller.

**teacher Model with Query:**

```
class teacher extends Model
{
  public static function teacher($id)
  {
   return DB::table('teachers')
   ->leftjoin('religions', 'teachers.religion_id', '=', 'religions.id')
   ->leftjoin('areas', 'teachers.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
   ->select('teachers.*','religions.*','areas.*')
   ->where('teachers.id',$id)
   ->first();
  }
```

**Controller which calls this model perfectly fine passing direct id:**

```
public function report1($id)
{
    $teacher = Teacher::teacher($id);
    return View('teachers.report1' ,compact('teacher'));
}
```

**Controller where I want to call it:**

```
public function printreports(Request $request)
{
    $teachers = $request->get('select2'); 
    return view('teachers.report1',compact('teachers'));
}
```

Note: `select2` contains teacher ids where I want to run model query.

Comment: Can you show example value for `select2` request parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you are have an array of ids in your select2 request param, probably easiest way is to change query at teacher model as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class teacher extends Model
{
  public static function teacher($id)
  {
   return DB::table('teachers')
   ->leftjoin('religions', 'teachers.religion_id', '=', 'religions.id')
   ->leftjoin('areas', 'teachers.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
   ->select('teachers.*','religions.*','areas.*')
   ->whereIn('teachers.id', Arr::wrap($id))
   ->get();
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe ->get() is better than ->first(), if the intent is get more than one teacher

Comment: Thank you. i had to add below line in my controller also;
$id = $request->get('select2');
$teachers = Teacher::teacher($id);